# Rust implementing merge-sorted iterator

Tags: iterator, rust

I'm trying to implement an iterator that merges two sorted iterators.  I'm running to issues borrowing fields from a struct.

How do I avoid this error?  I tried using borrowed references but that doesn't seem to help, since eventually I need to move the values of a_item and b_item.

```rust
use std::num::Saturating;

pub struct MergeSorted<A, T> {
    a: T,
    b: T,
    a_item: Option<A>,
    b_item: Option<A>,
}

impl<A: Ord, T: Iterator<A>> Iterator<A> for MergeSorted<A, T> {
    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<A> {

        match (self.a_item, self.b_item) {
            (None, None) => None,

            (None, Some(y)) => {
                let result = self.b_item;
                self.b_item = None;
                return result;
            }

            (Some(x), None) => {
                let result = self.a_item;
                self.a_item = self.a.next();
                result
            }

            (Some(x), Some(y)) => {
                if x < y {
                    let result = self.a_item;
                    self.a_item = self.a.next();
                    result
                } else {
                    let result = self.b_item;
                    self.b_item = self.b.next();
                    result
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #[inline]
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (uint, Option<uint>) {
        // stub
        (10, Some(100))
    }
}
```

Here's the specific error, this is repeated for all uses of self.a_item and self.b_item.

```
error: cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer
       match (self.a_item, self.b_item) {
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is this pattern:

```rust
let result = self.b_item;
self.b_item = None;
return result;
```

After the first line and before the second line `self.b_item` becomes moved out, making a "hole" in `self` (even if we forget that `self` is a borrowed pointer and you can't move out of it). This is not allowed. To express such pattern there is a special function in `std::mem`, called `replace`.

The second, main problem is that `A` is not implicitly copyable, so you when you try to match on values of type `Option<A>`, these values are moved out, but moving out from inside of `&/&mut` pointer is prohibited. The only way around this is to match on references. But then you should be careful, because borrowing rules only allow you to have single mutable borrow at a time. So you have to organize a kind of "flow" of references to `self.a_item` and `self.b_item` through the match statement, using pattern bindings.

The following code compiles. You can also replace `result` variable and `Some()` usage in the body of `match` directly with `mem::replace()` calls, but I thought that separating values selection and `mem::replace()` call make the code cleaner. Also I couldn't use `Some(x)` and `Some(y)` patterns in the last `match` arm because the references themselves are moved into `a_item` and `b_item`.

```rust
use std::mem;

pub struct MergeSorted<A, T> {
    a: T,
    b: T,
    a_item: Option<A>,
    b_item: Option<A>,
}

impl<A: Ord, T: Iterator<A>> Iterator<A> for MergeSorted<A, T> {
    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<A> {
        let result = match (&mut self.a_item, &mut self.b_item) {
            (&None, &None) => None,
            (&None, b_item @ &Some(_)) => Some((b_item, None)),
            (a_item @ &Some(_), &None) => Some((a_item, self.a.next())),
            (a_item @ &Some(_), b_item @ &Some(_)) => Some(
                if a_item.get_ref() < b_item.get_ref() {
                    (a_item, self.a.next())
                } else {
                    (b_item, self.b.next())
                }
            )
        };

        result.and_then(|(dest, value)| mem::replace(dest, value))
    }

    #[inline]
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (uint, Option<uint>) {
        // stub
        (10, Some(100))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation, that was trickier than I thought it would be.

Comment: Shouldn't `Some((b_item, None))` actually be `Some((b_item, self.b.next()))`? Otherwise, we silently discard all the next elements from `b`. (Anyway, this is a very nice approach. +1)

Comment: @chi I now think that the algorithm as a whole is not complete. Note that if `a_item` and `b_item` both are `None`, the `next()` method will return `None`. Therefore, you have to initialize `*_item` fields with some values from iterators somewhere, otherwise it just won't work. The purpose here was to demonstrate how the original code can be made to compile (note that the issue you've mentioned is present in the original code too). Overall, Shepmaster's answer is much nicer and that's what I'd use if I had to.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Yes, I assumed that at construction time the `*_item` fields are initialized using `*.next()`. Shepmaster's is simpler, but your approach is also interesting in its use of references. When I tried to do this as a learning exercise, I ended up with a very messy code performing several `mem::swap`s. I used an `ungetc`-like iterator, where you can put back the last item moved from the iterator. Messy. You instead simply compute the references and then `mem::replace` only once at the end, which is far more elegant in my eye.

Answer (score 6):

This solution works with Rust 1.2 and up.

Instead of keeping our own `Option` of items, I opted to use the [`peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) iterator adapter. This allows us to look forward one item without losing it.

I also broke down the `Iterator::next` method into two parts - one that determines from which side to pull, and one that actually advances that iterator.

There's also general updates for how iterators are now defined with associated types.

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct MergeAscending<L, R>
where
    L: Iterator<Item = R::Item>,
    R: Iterator,
{
    left: Peekable<L>,
    right: Peekable<R>,
}

impl<L, R> MergeAscending<L, R>
where
    L: Iterator<Item = R::Item>,
    R: Iterator,
{
    fn new(left: L, right: R) -> Self {
        MergeAscending {
            left: left.peekable(),
            right: right.peekable(),
        }
    }
}

impl<L, R> Iterator for MergeAscending<L, R>
where
    L: Iterator<Item = R::Item>,
    R: Iterator,
    L::Item: Ord,
{
    type Item = L::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<L::Item> {
        let which = match (self.left.peek(), self.right.peek()) {
            (Some(l), Some(r)) => l.cmp(r),
            (Some(_), None) => Ordering::Less,
            (None, Some(_)) => Ordering::Greater,
            (None, None) => return None,
        };

        match which {
            Ordering::Less => self.left.next(),
            Ordering::Equal => self.left.next(),
            Ordering::Greater => self.right.next(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let left = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
    let right = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

    let result: Vec<_> = MergeAscending::new(left.iter(), right.iter()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution to merge multiple sorted iterators, there is [kmerge](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.5/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.kmerge) method in itertools